# UserFrosting save twig render output to a variable then write to a file

Tags: php, twig, userfrosting

I want to save twig render output to variable and then write into a file. Normally, Twig in other projects would behave like this:

```
$bob = $this->render('index.html.twig',[
'foo' => $foo,
'token' => $token
]);
$bob->getContent();
```

However, with **UserFrosting** framework, $this->_app->render does not return any string and it echo the output right away.

For example:

```
$output=$this->_app->render('proposal/create-seo-proposal.twig');
```

Is there any way to capture the output generated by $this->_app->render ?

Answer (score 1):

spent sometimes looking into the UserFrosting code.

Realize $app is created on Slim Framework with Twig.

Therefore, Slim Framework got a few options to choose beside render function.

Therefore, this works:

```
$output=$this->_app->view->fetch(template-name.twig)
```

then save $output in a file or store it somewhere.

Cheers,